# jQuery.param and UTF-8

Tags: jquery, utf-8, hebrew

I have the following code:

```
var words = new Object(); 

$("li.words").each(function(){
   var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
   words[thisId] = $(this).children('input#word').val();
});
```

The input with id #word contains words in Hebrew (i.e. UTF-8 chars). 
When I use:

```
alert($.param(words));
```

the words look like this: *%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%*, instead of Hebrew characters.

This is weird, because if I try to alert a Hebrew word like so:

```
alert('עברית');
```

it works just fine. Even if I use a variable and alert it (without $.param).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm stupid.

the solution was:

```
alert(decodeURI($.param(grpNames_he)));
```

I just used it wrong a couple of times and thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) function. It decodes such chars as far as i can remember.